# how to insert data from mysql into html and vice versa, having radio button while inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, html

how can I insert data into mysql using radio button while inside the while loop.my code is something like this.

```
<form><table>
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>

       <tr><td>
       <input type='radio' name ="select[]" value=<?php echo $row['tid'] ?> /></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="age"/></td>
       </tr> 
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>
    </table></form>



     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
for($i=0;$i<count($select);$i++){
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO disasterTbl (field, field2, field3) VALUES('$radioButton_value here', '$value', $value)")or die(mysql_error());

        }
}
```

please help thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: Keep the `<form>` and `<table>` tags out of the loop. And you forgot to put a label for your radio button, there should always be two of them right?, Either an `on` or `off`, `yes` or `no` value.

Comment: if you mean what i think, then no, you cannot store information from a radio button that a user clicked while that radio didnt sent to user yet. Is that right?

Comment: i think i posted the question wrong. what i really want to do is after the user selected a radio button, he then will type the name and the age, and after clicking the submit button only the row which has the value of the selected radio button will be inserted in the new database,

Comment: Hmmm... you definitely did. You did not show the whole scenario. Give us an example of how the form looked before submission, how many pairs of radio buttons are there?

Comment: Is this the way your form looked or is going to look? See here: http://www.huinda.com/test/

Comment: no it does not look that way. the number of the radio buttons will depend on the previous database. can i send you a part of my code or something?

Answer (score 0):

You must send this data using $_GET or $_POST, and when you do that you must insert this data to table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit general, but something like this:

```
<form method="post">
<table>
<?php while ...
   <input type='radio' name ="select" ...
?>
</form>
...
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && isset($_POST['select'])) {
   $pdo = new PDO('host', 'user', 'pass');
   $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (?)")->execute($_POST['select']);
   header('Location:', true, 303);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: I think the question is wrong... I rephrased it a bit. I think he wanted to display the radio button with the correct values as stored from the database.

Comment: whenever i tried to use the foor loop inside the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) error says that Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @freeloader You may need to show that part, the handler for the submission.

Comment: hi, I added the part inside the if -submit.

Comment: @freeloader How do you handle the `$radioButton_value`, show it also.

Comment: i think i posted the question wrong. what i really want to do is after the user selected a radio button, he then will type the name and the age, and after clicking the submit button only the row which has the value of the selected radio button will be inserted in the new database,

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the radio button from the above example:

- if your form method is `POST`, then use `$_POST['select']`,
- or if method is `GET`, then use `$_GET['select']`
- or you can use `$_REQUEST['select']` for all methods.

Remember also, your radio must be **SET/checked**, otherwise you will not pass the required variable at all.

There should also be a pair of tags with type radio [one is set and one is not], to set/unset before a form submit.

EDIT:

```
    Radio: if ($row['tid'] == "1") {
echo "Yes <input type='radio' name='select' checked> No <input type='radio' name='select'>"; } 
else { echo "Yes <input type='radio' name='select'> No <input type='radio' name='select' checked >"; }
```

So in your query it should be coded as:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO disasterTbl (field, field2, field3) VALUES('$_POST["select"]', '$value', '$value')")or die(mysql_error());

or

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO disasterTbl (field, field2, field3) VALUES('$_GET["select"]', '$value', '$value')")or die(mysql_error());

or

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO disasterTbl (field, field2, field3) VALUES('$_REQUEST["select"]', '$value', '$value')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Tip: You can monitor the values of the submitted form by a simple `print_r($_REQUEST);` and it should show the `name`, `age`, `select` contained in the array.

EDIT: Also I noticed, your radio name is `select[]` instead of `select`, remove the brackets so it won't be treated as an array.

Comment: it does not work, values for the name and the age they do not match the value of the radio button

Comment: See this link if this is the way your form looks, you really need to show the whole scenario, we are left here crawling in the dark. See this link: http://www.huinda.com/test/

Comment: i do appreciate all the help. ok, for example, when i choose a radio button and then i clicked submit, all the information from the previous table that is associated to the value of the selected radio button should be also displayed when i clicked submit.

Comment: Yes, you have to have an if.. else condition inside the while loop, append "checked" in the radio button if the value in the database is "1" or "yes", whichever you used. e.g. `if ($row['tid'] == "1") echo "Yes <input type='radio' name='select' checked> No <input type='radio' name='select'>"; else echo "Yes <input type='radio' name='select'> No <input type='radio' name='select' checked >"`